# AJAX data not coming to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have JavaScript code to send the data to PHP.

Why I can't get the JSON data?

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var url = "http://192.168.1.4/temp.php";
xhr.open("POST", url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
        var json = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    }
}

var aa = [{
    "email": "hey@mail.com",
    "password": "101010"
}, {
    email: 'lo@mail.com',
    "passqword": "112"
}];
xhr.send(aa);
```

And I have created the PHP code like this to get the data:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'); 
    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    $v = json_decode(stripslashes(file_get_contents("php://input")));
    echo $v;
?>
```

Comment: Read up on [`$_POST`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php)

Comment: there is nothing about the json data

Comment: what's showing in console?

Answer (score 1):

`stripslashes` is likely to break the JSON that you are submitting (although given the particular input in this example, it will have no effect at all, there are no slashes).

More to the point, the return value of `json_decode` is a PHP array. The function expects JSON as **input**.

When you echo `$v`, you have a PHP array and not JSON.

Since what you are outputting is not JSON, `JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);` will fail.